# What are the advanced fusion techniques for fusing 3 band multispectral and 242 band hyperion hyperspectral dataset?

Tags: remote-sensing, digital-image-processing

I have used some of the image sharpening techniques such as Wavelet, Gram-schmidt, Principal component, Brovey. Other than this what are the new and advanced fusion techniques and in which software it can be implemented.